# Visual paradigm not null constraint

Tags: nullable, shortcut, erp, visual-paradigm

In Visual paradigm I write + before name of variable for declaring it as primary key (For example  `+id:int4` , is here any short way mark it not nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Visual Paradigm do not support specify the column to be nullable/not null via the inline editing interface. But with the **Property Pane** opened it at least allow you to change this property in a single click without go through the specification dialog. Maybe this can be a workaround.

[image]